# How to disable a button when state changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I am using trying to disable a button in react based on couple states. Down below is a breakdown of my code

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        pass: '',
        disabled: true
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePass = this.handlePass.bind(this);
}
```

pretty self explanatory constructor. The disabled will be changed as state changes. My render method looks something like this

```
render() {

    if(this.state.email && this.state.pass) {
        this.setState({ disabled: false })
    }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='top'></div>
            <div className='card'>
                <MuiThemeProvider>
                    <Card >
                        <div className='wrapper'>
                            <TextField
                                hintText="Email"
                                value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange}
                            /><br/>
                            <TextField
                                hintText="Password"
                                type="password"
                            /><br/>
                            <div className='login-btn'>
                                <RaisedButton label="Login" primary={true}
                                              disabled={this.state.disabled} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Card>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

As you can see I have 2 text fields and I am handeling the data changes with the following method

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({email: e.target.value});
}

handlePass(e) {
    this.setState({pass: e.target.value});
}
```

Now my button is initially disabled and everytime a state is changed and component re-renders I want to check for state changes and enable button accordingly. So I was thinking of using the life cycle method like so

```
componentWillMount() {
        if(this.state.pass && this.state.disabled) {
            this.setState({disabled: false})
        }
    }
```

However, this doesn't work. When both email and password field is not empty the button stays disabled. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: iam not quite sure here, but you have a RaisedButton component. Is this a valid html button, because, as far as i know only buttons my be disabled

Comment: @Paulquappe It is valid; the syntax is part of [React](https://reactjs.org/).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just made a demo , is that you need, check the code in the demo below

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8jljzu)

Change below code :

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        pass: '',
        invalidData: true
    }
    this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
    this.onPasswordChange = this.onPasswordChange.bind(this);
}

  // componentWillUpdate is to be deprecated
  //componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  //  nextState.invalidData = !(nextState.email && nextState.pass);
  //}  


  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value });
  }

  onPasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({ pass: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onEmailChange} placeholder="Email" />
        <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.onPasswordChange} placeholder="Password" />
        // from this <button disabled={this.state.invalidData}>Submit</button>
    //to
     <button disabled={!(this.state.email && this.state.password)}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**updated **

disable submit button in `<button disabled={!(this.state.email && this.state.password)}>Submit</button>` itself.

Comment: can you check the answer again, answer updated @Shadid

Answer (score 2):

Please, do not set states inside `render()` function. That might cause infinite loops to occur.

Refer: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5591

Instead of setting states inside `render()` function, you can set the disabled state inside the `handleChange()` and `handlePass()` function.

If more detail required, please do mention.

Answer (score -1):

You should be setting the `disabled` state inside your `handleChange` and `handlePass` functions.

`componentWillMount()` only runs right before the component is rendered, but never again.

Comment: No explanation for the downvote?